# Wordpress - avada theme, jerky header and logo jumps out of sticky header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a site that I'm doing some tweaks on and everything is done except for some logo/header issues.

I have a sticky header with animation which causes it to create a smaller size sticky header with a new logo, but the sticky header animation is a bit jerky and if you scroll back up quickly the logo jumps out of the bottom of the header for a second. It looks really strange for the user.

The site is at [www.Dev.smithermancpa.com](http://dev.smithermancpa.com) and you can scroll the page and see it in action.

I changed the animationDuration in the avada-header.js file which helped a bit (going from 300 ms to 100 ms) but is there a more distinct fix for this issue? I've seen a lot of smooth sticky header animations before so I'm sure there is a known good way to do this that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am struggling with the same problem. Avada 5.2.1 at the moment.

What I've seen in all browsers is a two step animation. Big logo to small logo and no animation steps in between.

I think I found a way to immediately get a smoother animation. I set a background for the logo but make the background transparent. There is a theme setting for logo background. Make it black and drag opacity to the bottom.